# How to remove CALayer when done animating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a view in which I draw all my CALayers inside the drawRect method. Inside the method I start the animation, and on the completion block I remove the layer and its sublayer from the super layer. However, it keeps getting added back as a sublayer in my animation. How do I prevent this from happening?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

...

[CATransaction begin];
    {
        [CATransaction setAnimationDuration: 5.0];//Dynamic Duration
        [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
            [tutorialCircle removeFromSuperlayer];
            [strokePart removeFromSuperlayer];
        }];
...

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            strokePart = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
            strokePart.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
            strokePart.frame = tutorialCircle.bounds;
            strokePart.path = tutorialCircle.path;
            strokePart.lineCap = tutorialCircle.lineCap;
            strokePart.lineWidth = tutorialCircle.lineWidth;
...

[tutorialCircle addSublayer: strokePart];
```

How do I make sure that my sublayer and its sublayer are just shown for the animation for one time and then gone forever?

Answer (score -1):

I had to set the opacity of both to 0 along with removing them for some reason. Weird.

```
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
            [tutorialCircle removeFromSuperlayer];
            tutorialCircle.opacity = 0.0;
            strokePart.opacity = 0.0;
            [strokePart removeFromSuperlayer];
        }];
```